# Fake proof that $(5)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbf{Z}[i]$

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, fake-proofs

Here's a (false) proof that $(5)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbf{Z}[i]$. I've been trying to spot the mistake, but I can't seem to find it.

Here's how the proof goes: to show that $(5)$ is a prime ideal, we will show that the quotient $\mathbf{Z}[i]/(5)$ is a field. Since we can write $\mathbf{Z}[i] \cong \mathbf{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$, we have

$$(\mathbf{Z}[i])/(5) \cong (\mathbf{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 1))/(5) \cong \mathbf{F}_5[x]/(x^2 + 1) \cong \mathbf{F}_5, $$
where the last isomorphism follows since $x^2 +1$ is reducible in $\mathbf{F}_5$. Since $\mathbf{F}_5$ is a field, this shows that $(5)$ is prime. Where's the mistake?

I'm thinking that the isomorphism $(\mathbf{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 1))/(5) \cong \mathbf{F}_5[x]/(x^2 + 1) $ isn't correct, but I'm fairly sure that when quotienting by two ideals, we can switch the order like this; i.e: quotienting by $(x^2 + 1)$ and then by $(5)$ is the same as doing it in the opposite order. Any corrections would be most welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $K$ is any field, $x^2+1$ being reducible in $K[x]$ does not imply $K[x]/(x^2+1) \simeq K$. (Just note that the left hand side has $K$-dimension $2$, as $\dim_K (K[x]/(f)) = \deg(f)$ in general.) Rather, this is $\simeq K \times K$ (unless $\mathrm{char}(K)=2$, but even then it's not $K$, see below).

Actually, check for yourself that if $p = (x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_n) \in K[x]$, with distinct $a_i$, then $K[x]/(p) \simeq K \times ... \times K$ ($n$-fold product).

**Added**: It's asked in a comment whether the above is still true for more general rings $R$ instead of a field $K$. Note that we certainly have $R[x]/(x-a) \simeq R$ (via $x \mapsto a$) for any $a \in R$. But since the proof of $K[x]/\prod(x-a_i) \simeq \prod K[x]/(x-a_i)$ is basically the Chinese Remainder Theorem (a.k.a. Sun-Tsu theorem), that depends on whether its conditions still hold for $R$ instead of $K$.

Well, for any commutative ring $R$ and elements $a,b \in R$, the ideals $(x-a)$ and $(x-b)$ in $R[x]$ are coprime if and only if $a-b \in R^\times$. So if all pairwise differences $a_i - a_j (i \neq j)$ are units in $R$, then the conclusion still holds. (Note how for $R=K$ this reduces to the above condition that all the $a_i$ are different from each other.)

In the particularly easy example of $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ we see that as soon as $2 \in R^\times$, we get $R[x]/(x^2-1) \simeq R[x]/(x-1) \times R[x]/(x+1) \simeq R \times R$. In particular, this is true for all $R= \mathbb Z/n$ with *odd* $n$.

However if $2 \notin R^\times$, this can fail; indeed, as alluded to above, already for a field $R=K$ with $\mathrm{char}(K)=2$, the ring $$K[x]/(x^2-1) \simeq K[x]/(x^2+1) \simeq K[x]/(x-1)^2 \; \stackrel{x-1 \;\mapsto \,t}\simeq \; K[t]/(t^2)$$
is *not* isomorphic to $K \times K$: they share the same underlying additive group, but unlike $K \times K$, the ring above contains an element $x\neq 1$ with $x^2=1$ (or an element $t \neq 0$ with $t^2=0$).

Consequently, we also have $R[x]/(x^2-1) \not \simeq R \times R$ for any ring $R$ such that $R/(2)$ is a field (because such an isomorphism would, modulo $2$, induce an isomorphism in the case of a field which we just excluded). This includes all the $R=\mathbb Z/n$ with *even* $n$.

As a last remark, I suspect there *are* rings $R$ with $2 \notin R^\times$ where $R[x]/(x^2-1) \simeq R \times R$ still holds, "accidentally" i.e. in spite of a proof via the Chinese Remainder Theorem failing. I do not have a concrete example for that (in spite of what I wrote here earlier, the candidate I proposed there failed I think), but there are rings $R$ which happen to be $\simeq R \times R$; there are rings $R$ such that $R[x]/(x^2-1) \simeq R$; and I see no reason why there should not be some weird big ring where both these isomorphisms hold, simultaneously, accidentally.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. I should have guessed -- the proof is basically the Sun-Tsu theorem!

Comment: A (late) follow-up question to this: does this result still hold if we replace $K$ with a ring $R$? For example, do we have $\mathbf{Z}/25\mathbf{Z}[x]/(x^2 -1) \cong \mathbf{Z}/25\mathbf{Z} \times \mathbf{Z}/25\mathbf{Z}$? (Note that $x^2 - 1$ splits into linear factors in $\mathbf{Z}/25\mathbf{Z}$. ) Or is the result only true for fields?

Comment: Will follow up with an edit soon, already prepared that with an edit regarding characteristics in the field case. I think yes, this is true over any ring in which $2$ is a unit, which of course includes any $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ for odd $n$.